# jQuery Foreach: performing same function on different ids

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js and foreach image dropped in it I should perform the same function "on success" handler. Specifically foreach image I should be able to insert `title` and `description`. I have something like this

[image]

And I can handle the success event as following:

```
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, response) {
        //Here I get the response with the image id
        file.serverId = response;

        //Then I display the successful icon
        file.thumbnail = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/file_icon.png";

        //I can store the image id returned
        var id = file.serverId;

        //here my problem start. I've thought to assign the id to the relative image fields "title" and "description"
        jQuery( "#itemtitle" ).prop( "id","itemtitle-"+id);
        jQuery( "#itemdescription" ).prop( "id","itemdescription-"+id );

        //as screenshot displays, I should use the button "update informations" and update the relative metas
        jQuery( "#updateinformations" ).prop( "id","updateinformations-"+id );
        var updateinfo = $('#updateinformations-'+id);

        //on click I should perform this function for each image (ids)
        updateinfo.on("click", function() {
            var itemtitle = $('#itemtitle-'+id).val();
            var itemdescription = $('#itemdescription-'+id).val();

            //In fact here I'm trying to send all the infos to my AJAX action
            update_info(id, itemtitle, itemdescription);
        });
    });
```

My problem, at now, is that the code upload infos but, for example, if I place 2 images, the second gets the title of the first one and so on.
How could I assign the correct informations foreach image?

Comment: Use attr in place of prop

Comment: @SunilPachlangia Thanks for your help! I actually had to change my whole approach...